# Connecting Phoenix app to MS SQL Azure database

Tags: sql-server, azure, elixir, phoenix-framework

I am trying to connect a phoenix application to MS SQL. After looking around online I came across a couple of adapters called [mssql_ecto](https://github.com/findmypast-oss/mssql_ecto) & [mssqlex](https://github.com/findmypast-oss/mssqlex).

I have added them to the project following the instructions in the readme, installed odbc and checked that the db is online but I am now getting the following error..

```
[error] Mssqlex.Protocol (#PID<0.13069.0>) failed to connect: ** (Mssqlex.Error) odbc_not_started
```

My app is configured as below..

```
config :my_app, MyApp.Repo,
adapter: MssqlEcto,
username: "<my_username>",
password: "<my_password>",
database: "test",
hostname: "<my_server>.database.windows.net", 
pool_size: 10
```

My environment is as follows..

- MacOS Sierra 10.12.5
- Elixir version: 1.4.4

There is an issue in the mssql_ecto repo already, and I have tried the suggestions from there, but it still has not worked.

If anyone has managed to connect their phoenix/elixir application to MSSQL on macOS and could provide some instructions it would be greatly appreciated (even if it was done in a completely different way to my approach  ).

Side note: Tried it in node with the same db and was able to connect to and query the db.

Comment: As a debugging step, are you able to connect to the database from sort of database app?

Answer (score 2):

I've been working through the same issue this week, connecting to an Azure SQL Database, and this is what I've got working.

You are seeing the first of 2 main problems I ran into:

1. Erlang installed without ODBC
2. Mssqlex adapter is missing required configuration options

**#1: Erlang installed without ODBC**

If you've installed Elixir and Erlang using brew, or something like it, you are getting an installation of Erlang that does not include erlang-odbc.  In order to remedy this, you will need to install Erlang from source.

I recommend that you install both Erlang and Elixir from source using the method documented here:
http://www.lambdacat.com/how-to-install-elixir-on-mac/

Just make sure that you remove the Kerl option, `--without-odbc`, before you build Erlang.

Now that you have Erlang installed correctly, the `odbc_not_started` error should go away... to be replaced by connection errors to the database.

**#2: Mssqlex adapter is missing required configuration options**

As of this moment, the [mssqlex](https://github.com/findmypast-oss/mssqlex) adapter does not support the following configuration options that Azure is looking for:

1. Encrypt
2. TrustServerCertificate
3. Connection Timeout

To get around this issue, I [forked the mssqlex library](https://github.com/tvanhouten/mssqlex) and added those options [in a branch](https://github.com/tvanhouten/mssqlex/tree/azure-settings).  I am not committing to maintaining this so feel free to fork it yourself.

In order to use the modified mssqlex, replace the mix dependency with the github location and branch name:

```
{:mssqlex, git: "https://github.com/tvanhouten/mssqlex.git", branch: "azure-settings", override: true}
```

The `override: true` is important because mssql_ecto has a dependency on the mssqlex version in hex.

Now you can update your configuration:

```
config :my_app, MyApp.Repo,
adapter: MssqlEcto,
username: "<my_username>",
password: "<my_password>",
database: "test",
hostname: "<my_server>.database.windows.net", 
pool_size: 10,
encrypt: "yes",
trust_server_certificate: "no",
connection_timeout: "30
```

**Other "Gotchas" to Look Out For**

*Azure requires TCP connection:*

In order to connect to an Azure SQL Database, you will need to make sure that the `hostname:` option starts with `tcp:`.  So, all together, it will look like
    hostname: "tcp:.database.windows.net"

*Mssql_ecto does not support Ecto 2.2+:*

If you're getting errors related to Ecto or Ecto.SubQuery, you probably need to make sure that you are using a version of Ecto that is supported by mssql_ecto. At this point in time, that means Ecto 2.1.x.  Again, this requires a slight change to your mix dependencies:

```
{:ecto, ">= 2.1.0 and < 2.2.0"}
```

*Dependency cache and lock issues:*

If everything seems to be in order according to the above but it just doesn't seem like the new dependencies are being updated and compiled as expected, do the following:

1. Run `mix deps.clean --all`
2. Delete the `mix.lock` file from your root project directory
3. Run `mix deps.get`
4. Run `mix deps.compile`

That should do it!